# MapInfo 17.0.1. Problems with SQL queries for my database

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapinfo

I am writing to you with the following two problems I have with MapInfo at my workplace. Recently we have changed our Microsoft SQL-Server 2003, with MapInfo Spatialware, to a Microsoft SQL Server 2019. This has led to problems mostly with SQL queries which can not be loaded or can not be executed, because Mapinfo crashes.

My problem that I have is about the SQL queries that I have. We use them at my workplace to receive/filter/extract specific objects, for example roads, from our database for maps that we create. So here I refer to the SQL Query dialogbox which you can open in MapInfo, when you want to load something from your database.

If I want to execute a larger query to receive specific roads from our road database, as example with the size of round about 60 lines with CASE statements, MapInfo crashes. All of these queries worked before we switched our server with either MapInfo 12.5 or newer versions like MapInfo 17.0.
I have edited the syntax of the queries so that they can be used with the newer SQL version. The only thing I could imagine that the query is too complex or some kind of limit is reached and because of that MapInfo crashes.

Example for a query:

```
Select     
n.SATZ_NUMMER,
CASE n.NR_Projekt_1 % 100
WHEN d.Wert THEN n.NR_Projekt_1/1000
ELSE
CASE n.NR_Projekt_2 % 100
WHEN d.Wert THEN n.NR_Projekt_2/1000
ELSE
CASE n.NR_Projekt_3 % 100
WHEN d.Wert THEN n.NR_Projekt_3/1000
END 
END 
END 
AS BSTR_WB, 
d.Dringlichkeit,
g.MI_PRINX,  
g.SP_GEOMETRY
FROM    
"BMVKarte-ng".dbo.NETZ_G g,  "BMVKarte-ng".dbo.Strecken n, "BMVKarte-ng".dbo.Dringlichkeit d
WHERE     (
(d.Dringlichkeit = 'WB')
    and
(n.SATZ_NUMMER = g.SATZ_NUMMER)
    and 
        (
            (
                (n.NR_Projekt_1 > 200000) 
                    and 
                (n.NR_Projekt_1 < 300000)
                    and
                (n.NR_Projekt_1 % 100 = d.Wert) 
            )
                or
            (
                (n.NR_Projekt_2 > 200000) 
                    and 
                (n.NR_Projekt_2 < 300000)
                    and
                (n.NR_Projekt_2 % 100 = d.Wert) 
            )
                or  
            (
                (n.NR_Projekt_3 > 200000) 
                    and 
                (n.NR_Projekt_3 < 300000)
                    and
                (n.NR_Projekt_3 % 100 = d.Wert) 
            )
        )
    
)
```

Sorry that I was not able to describe certain steps in a better way, but unfortunately my MapInfo is in German…

I tried to conntact the MapInfo tech support via e-mail and phone, but I did not receive an anwser.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, with a One question per Question policy. GIS SE is not supposed to replace software vendor defect reporting procedures, so you should certainly send notification of these issues through the customary/contracted mechanism. We can't do much about crashes with legal SQL, but if you post the simplest query which also fails, maybe someone can think of an alternative (like fashioning a view, then making the query much less complex). Please focus this Question on your most pressing issue.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Hopefully the changes I have made are as you meant them to be.

Comment: There seems to be a number of potential issues to review. Have you tried using a legal SQL database name (renaming database `"BMVKarte-ng"` to `BMVKarte_ng`)? Have you tried using a JOIN instead of a FROM table list? Have you tried fashioning the query as a view, then making the query `SELECT * FROM viewname`?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I tried your ideas but unfortunately they did not work. Still I was able to fix the problem for some queries at least by editing them so there is no need for a CASE statement. Honestly I do not really understand why this helps, because before we changed our SQL Server those queries were working… But I guess this is a typical problem with switching servers… Hopefully my solution will work with all of the problematic queries.

Comment: The SQL supported by 2003 isn't even the same language as 2019. If the SQL hasn't been ported to the modern implementation, then it isn't a MapInfo issue that it doesn't work, and you should be researching the SQL difficulties in [dba.se].

Comment: Make sure you reach out to Precisely Tech Support these days: software.support@precisely.com. Let me know if you still don't get any response form them

Comment: Must admit that it has been a decade or so since I worked with SpatialWare. As I recall you used to have to pass the Select statement to a procedure in the database, right? Could that in some way influence the problems you are seeing? You have not been able to make these statements work with any version of MapInfo Pro, true? At some point I got the understanding that they worked with an older version of MapInfo Pro reading your thread again it seems that was before you switched to pure SQL Server.

Comment: Also, you do not mention the MapInfo_MapCatalog which holds info for your spatial tables. I assume you have updated these to reflect that you now are using SQL Server instead of SpatailWare, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late anwser! Thanks for your answer Peter! Thanks for the e-mail address. I tried to contact your colleagues at Precisely via the online contact formular and the German hotline. To your questions: Sorry I forgot to mention that I was using MapInfo Pro and yes unfortunately it dose not work with older versions. At my workplace some PC´s also have MapInfo Pro 12.5. but there MapInfo also crashes after we switched to our new server. And yes, so far I did not misunderstood my colleagues, we updated the spatial tables.